# is there any way to disable file filter options in save button in the toolbar of jasperreport viewer

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I would like to know is there any way to remove `pdf,xls` in save button option files of type different formats so that i dont want to generate reports in pdf singlesheet-xls.

Generally the default save button files of type option comes with all the formats -`pdf,singlesheet xls,embedded images,jrxml,multiplesheet xls,csv` and other formats.
what i want is to disable `pdf` and singlesheet `xls`.is there any way to disable certain formats in ireport

Comment: What is the reason to deny some kind of export options in iReport? This is a GUI designer and this is not end-user application for building reports.

Answer (score 2):

This example removes all save options apart from **Single sheet XLS** and **PDF**:

```
JRViewer viewer = ... ;//your viewer
JRSaveContributor[] contrbs = viewer.getSaveContributors();

for (JRSaveContributor saveContributor : contrbs)
{
    if (!(saveContributor instanceof net.sf.jasperreports.view.save.JRSingleSheetXlsSaveContributor 
            || saveContributor instanceof net.sf.jasperreports.view.save.JRPdfSaveContributor))
        viewer.removeSaveContributor(saveContributor);
}
```

Comment: i'm not getting JRViewer viewer = ......;//your viewer  Please explain me sir...Thanks for you reply

Comment: You have to obtain an instance of JRViewer class somehow. How do you present your report to the user?